# I get different results from the "same query" in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

### My Case

I have three entities: `student`, `subject` and `teacher` which are structured as follows:

```java
@Entity(name = "Student")
@Table(name = "Student")
public class Student
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;
    
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
    private List<Subject> subjectList = new ArrayList<Subject>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
    private List<Teacher> teacherList = new ArrayList<Teacher>();
}
```

```java
@Entity(name = "Subject")
@Table(name = "Subject")
public class Subject
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
    private Student student;
}
```

```java
@Entity(name = "Teacher")
@Table(name = "Teacher")
public class Teacher
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
    private Student student;
}
```

**Student**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| A | Albert |
| B | Jack |

**Subject**

| id | name | student_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Math | A |
| 2 | History | B |
| 3 | Math | B |
| 4 | English | A |

**Teacher**

| id | name | student_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mr. H | B |
| 2 | Mr. E | B |
| 3 | Mr. L | A |
| 4 | Mr. P | A |

### My Problem

I get two different results based on the type of method I try to get the results back, in fact neither of them is correct.

#### Method 1

```java
StatelessSession session = getSession();
Student student = (Student) session.get(Student.class, "A");
```

In this case, the id, name and subjectList properties are returned to me correctly. But teacherList is empty!

#### Method 2

```java
StatelessSession session = getSession();
Query<V> query = session.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM Student WHERE id = :id", Student.class);

List<V> list = query
        .setParameter("id", "A")
        .list();
```

In this second case, the object inside the list contains the properties: id, name and teacherList. But not subjetList, absurd!

***How can I correctly return the "Student" object? What am I doing wrong?***

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:

- the mapping
- the stateless session

Remove the `@JoinColumn` from `Student` and use `mappedBy`:

```
@Entity(name = "Student")
@Table(name = "Student")
public class Student
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;
    
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    private List<Subject> subjectList = new ArrayList<Subject>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    private List<Teacher> teacherList = new ArrayList<Teacher>();
}
```

You can find more examples about [mapping bidirectional one-to-many](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many) in the documentation.

[A stateless session has many limitations](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#_statelesssession), two of which are:

> - Lazy loading of associations is not supported.
> - Collections are ignored by a stateless session.

In this case it would make more sense to use a regular `Session`. This way lazy loading will work.

Note that mapping an association as eager is usually not recommended unless you know that you always want to load the associations every time you load a student.

Comment: Do you change anything inside the `Subject` and `Teacher` classes?

Comment: No, but you also have to use a regular session. I've updated my answer

Answer (score -1):

Try changing `FetchType` values from `LAZY` to `EAGER`. I think that's the problem. Since `FetchType.LAZY` mode implies loading data on request. `FetchType.EAGER`, in turn, loads the data with all the other fields

Comment: If I put them both to EAGER will throw the following exception: `org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags`

Comment: @G.Ciardini You can try remove `FetchType` from `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` annotations and try this `@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)` instead. Or if the situation allows you to change the `List` type to `Set`, this should also solve the problem. Hope it helps

Comment: Still got an error, `org.hibernate.SessionException: collections cannot be fetched by a stateless session`